# How to add menu subitem in magento website?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to add menu sub item in the existing parent menu but couldn't get good resource to help me out? can we add sub-item menu through magento admin panel?

Comment: Which Magento version and look your theme configuration, maybe you have that feature.

Comment: I am using magento 1.9.10 v

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default theme than you can easily create menu from admin panel
or you can use custom extension for this as well.

You can use below extension:

[Megamenu for Magento 1](https://www.rootways.com/shop/magento-mega-menu-extension)

This extension is easy to manage and you can add categories as you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. To start, simply go to Magento admin -> Catalog -> Manage
   Categories.
2. Manage categories page, you will notice 2 buttons which read ‘add
   root category’ and ‘add subcategory’. Note that a root category
   serves more as a placeholder for subcategories. In other words, you
   enter any categories that you want seen in your store as a
   subcategory within a root category.
3. By default, Magento has a ‘default category’ setup already. This
   default category is a root category.
4. You would add the category as a subcategory by clicking on a root
   category and then clicking the ‘add subcategory button’.
5. On the next page, you will need to enter a name for your subcategory
   which can be anything that you’d like.
6. For ‘is active’, you’d want to select “Yes” if you want the category to show in your store.
7. As for ‘include in navigation menu’, if you select “Yes”, your
   category will show up in the navigation menu.
8. Once you have finished entering your information, move onto the
   ‘display settings’ tab.
9. In the display mode, you have the option of choosing ‘products
   only’, ‘static block only’ and ‘static block and products’.
10. As for ‘is anchor’, if you select “Yes”, a layered navigation menu will appear on category pages.